# Angular JS material date picker not showing date correctly?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

Hello I have an issue with angular js material date picker not showing date correctly cause it's always one day less than the selected date. Here is my date picker

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="ctrl.myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" ></md-datepicker>
```

Is there a way to fix this? Please check this codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yoWdOY

Comment: Please check this clip https://www.screencast.com/t/afzAdOtGY

Comment: It seems to be working correctly in your codepen, `{{ctrl.myDate}}` prints the right date.

Comment: Then it's something to do with time zone I believe. Do you know how to fix that? Supposed I selected 08 september 2017, when I inserted the data to the database, it inserted 07 september 2017 instead.

Comment: Check your system clock.

Comment: Could you check this codepen: https://codepen.io/jadjoubran/pen/gaPoXg. Does it work correctly for you? Mine still doesn't.

Comment: Please check this screenshot https://www.screencast.com/t/hRw8xrJsyh

Comment: Yes, still works fine.

Comment: Any updates on this ?